# using dynamic keyword to cast to a value type...throws exception

Tags: c#, dynamic

Sorry for the long question :

I have some classes that all have InnerObject as a property.

```
public class MyInt
{
    int InnerObject;
}
public class MyLong
{
    long InnerObject;
}
public class MyString
{
    string InnerObject;
}
```

and so on ...

Please don't tell me I can use generics, or Don't ask me why I need these classes. Please read my question.

I have a some class called Foo that has a method called ProcessSomething :

```
public class Foo
{
    void Process(MyInt value)
    {  
      ...
    }
}
```

Now I have a framework code where I want to write some code like this -

I want to write code like this :

```
int myValue = 100;
MyInt myInt = new MyInt();
myInt.InnerObject = myValue;
myFoo.Process(myValue );
```

SO far so good but I have many different types of classes and their functions where I may have to pass MyString, MyLong etc....

So to ease this I tried to create a Utility class like this :

```
public static class MyTypes
{
   public static dynamic Convert<T>(T i)
   {
      dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
      x.InnerObject = i;
      return x;
    }
}
```

My intention was that I could write code like this   :

```
myFoo.Process(MyTypes.Convert<int>(myValue));
```

All this code compiles ,as expected, but at runtime I get an exception when I the above line is executed .
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to 'iInt32'

When I try to modify my Convert method to this :

```
public static K Convert<T,K>(T i)
{
    dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
    x.InnerObject = i;
    return (K)x;
}
```

and call it like this  ( even though I don't like it, but I tried to see if I can make it work)
    myFoo.Process(MyTypes.Convert(myValue));

I still get the exception : 
Cannot convert type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to 'iInt32'

Clearly I am not understanding something..Any help in clarifying my understanding would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you don't seem to understand is that `ExpondoObject` is not an `int`.  Thought I'm wondering why you didn't try to cast it to your `MyInt` class (spoiler that wouldn't work either).  `dynamic` is meant to be used when you don't know the type at runtime, not to just cast anything you want to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create `ExpandoObject`, it's not `MyInt`, `MyLong`, etc., so it cannot be cast to these classes.

You can add a [`new` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) to `MyTypes.Convert<T>`, and use `new T()` to create an object to return:

```
public static K Convert<T,K>(T i) where K : new()
{
    dynamic x = new K();
    x.InnerObject = i;
    return (K)x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish or if it's possible, but I can shed some light on the problem.

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.InnerObject = i;
return (K)x;
```

When you invoke this code using `int` for the generic type parameter `K`, then the last line will attempt to cast an `ExpandoObject` to an `int`.  There's no such conversion defined, so it fails.

Is there some reason you can't use `myFoo.Process(new MyInt(...))`?